# API post request not reaching the application

Tags: vue.js, axios, httprequest, vuex, laravel-api

i'm new to laravel and i'm facing a painful problem.

I'm using [Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart](https://github.com/Crinsane) in my ecommerce api and i'm trying to send a post request with axios in vuejs that adds a product to the cart by sending the product id and the quantity. The problem is the id and quantity are not reaching the application although i'm pretty sure i specified the correct route link in axios and i'm getting "No query results for model [App\Product]." which i assume means that the controller function that handles the request is working but the id is not being sent/transformed to the resource collection. I don't know if the problem is with the package i'm using or the code or something else.

this is axios request

```
   addCart(item) {
                 axios
                 .post('/api/cart/add', item)
                 .then(response => (response.data.data))
                 .catch(error => console.log(error.response.data))
```

this is the route :

```
Route::post('cart/add', [
  'uses' =>  'ShoppingController@store',
  'as' => 'cart.add'
]);
```

this is the cart collection

```
  public function toArray($request)
    {
      return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'qty' => $this->qty
      ];
    }
```

this is the controller

```
    public function store(){

      $pdt = Product::findOrFail(request()->id);
      
      $cart = Cart::add([
        'id' => $pdt->id,
        'name' => $pdt->name,
        'qty' => request()->qty,
        'price' => $pdt->price
      ]);
```

and this is the product model

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
      'name', 'description', 'image', 'category', 'quantity', 'price', 'sold','remaining','rating', 'bestSelling', 'featured'
    ];

}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Add the code for your model, controller, route, and axios request.

Comment: I created only one model for the products and i'm using the package for the cart functionality,do you need the product model or the cart model?

Comment: If you follow that original Axios request through the route it hits, the controller that route triggers and the Product model, that should be enough to see what the issue is, I'd be surprised if it was an issue with the cart package

Comment: @Daniel_Knights  I updated the question with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found that it needed a json object to work and i had to put this code at the end of the store method :

```
return response()->json(['cart' => $cart], 201);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in your controller.

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#accessing-the-request):

> To obtain an instance of the current HTTP request via dependency injection, you should type-hint the `Illuminate\Http\Request` class on your controller method.

Try this:

```
public function store(Request, $request){
      // Make sure the 'id' exists in the request
      if ($request->get('id')) {
        $pdt = Product::find($request->get('id'));

        if ($request->get('qty')) {
          $qty = $request->get('qty')
        }

        $cart = Cart::add([
          'id' => $pdt->id,
          'name' => $pdt->name,
          'qty' => $qty,
          'price' => $pdt->price
        ]);
      }
```

Then, at the top of your controller, add:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Comment: I tried it, "No query results" error is gone but when i try and dd($cart) it's a 500 error with "Undefined variable: cart"

Comment: If you `dd($request)` what does it say?

Comment: Likely means that `'id'` doesn't exist in the request so it's not entering that `if` block

Comment: Are you calling it outside the `if` block?

Comment: No inside the block

Comment: I tried sending the request from a blade template and placing the route in web.php and everything worked fine. The request went through and returned the collection. I think I'll skip the package and make my own cart functionality because all the requests i send to the api outside the package is working properly.

Comment: You need to `dd` outside the `if` block

Comment: I don't know how much of what you've posted is involving that package but it should be an easy fix if you stick with it

Comment: Reading through the docs it does look pretty confusing. Building a cart system from scratch will teach you more if you're fairly new to this but it's definitely not easy

Comment: yeah absolutely, thanks Daniel for your efforts. much appreciated

Comment: No trouble @Majdiden